# "Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' " How do I fix it?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 10000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Show alert letting the user know they have to turn this on.
        }
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centerViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            // Show alert instructing them how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // Show an alert letting them know what's up
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
}
```

How do I fix that? It is in the ending of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

to

```
extension ViewController {
```

Saying `CLLocationManagerDelegate` is *redundant*. That means you've already said it earlier, you don't need to say it again.

Alternatively, *don't* say it earlier. Say it here and *not* earlier. To do it that way, change

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

The point is that you only need to say it in one place.

Comment: That worked. But then i needed to add "privacy - Location When In used" in the info list and then it says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" behind the code on row 53 (mapView.showsUserLocation = true). How do I fix that?

Comment: After you say "that worked", that's the end. You can / should accept the answer (click the checkmark so that it turns green). If you then have _another_ question, ask a _new question_ (click the Ask Question) button. Don't use the comments to ask new questions that arise as a result of solving the first question.